# @id is not working inside Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-3.0, resource-id

As far as I know, the difference between @+id and @id is to create a resource id first time and reuse that already existed resource id in different places. For instance, If we have a Relative layout having two textViews one below another, we shall use @resourceId for the second textView which refers to the first TextView.
The problem is, after updating the android studio to 3.0, @resourceId is not working anymore.To place second textView below the first one, I need to use @+firstTextViewId instead of @firstTextViewId. More specifically I need to use,

```
android:layout_below="@+id/totalQty"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_below="@id/totalQty"
```

Here is the code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relBottomLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalQty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abcdef"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/totalQty"
        android:text="saasdfdsdfsdf"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalNetPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/totalPrice"
        android:text="abcdsadfsafddgfdgfgdef"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is it an understanding issue? or a problem from any end? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: did you try to clean and rebuild project

Comment: what is your root of your layout?

Comment: It's possible that the newer tools process files differently – not necessarily top-down – so it's hitting the `@id` before the `@+id`. Just use `@+id` everywhere. It's not going to hurt anything.

Comment: @Bek, Yes, same issues.

Comment: @EnamulHaque, Relative Layout is the root.

Comment: @MikeM., okay.!

Answer (score 0):

```
I just remove + sign at @+id from your code. Here's the updated code

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relBottomLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalQty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abcdef"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/totalQty"
        android:text="saasdfdsdfsdf"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalNetPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/totalPrice"
        android:text="abcdsadfsafddgfdgfgdef"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```